# How to implement Spotify-like iOS app sidebar feature

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation, ecslidingviewcontroller

I've already implemented a sidebar like that in Facebook/Path apps with [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) but I've noticed that Spotify app it's a bit different and has a very slick effect. The sidebar is not already full visible but it slides and show the icons as more as you swipe with your finger. How to animate the sidebar in this way?

Here an image for a better explanation.

[image: Spotify iOS App]

Comment: That's a table, so alter the position of the TableView as a function of the main view position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `MMDrawerController`  https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

It has nice sample app and allows custom sliding effects, including the one you are looking for

Comment: Lukas, I've checked that library and it's very cool! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I have discovered this one few days ago and was impressed too

Comment: It's very great because it has many animation. I hope it's flexible as `ECSlidingViewController` is.

Comment: Glad you guys like it. The parallax animation is my favorite one as well. It's also a very similar animation to the one found in iOS redacted :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many such libraries available to implement the behaviour you have asked for. I would recommend ECSlidingViewController since its easy to use plus it supports StoryBoards:

[ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)

As i said there are a lot of different libraries to implement the same thing. You can also check the link [HERE](http://bitly.com/bundles/o_27ukkruo5l/1) that contains a whole list of similar libraries.

Comment: As I said in the post I'm already using `ECSlidingViewController` but it doesn't support the behavior I've explained.